# What's the song playing while kakashi and his dad are talking? (episode 175)

Tags: naruto

video link: https://youtu.be/ccOv9fh38aI?t=70

from 1:10 to the end of the video

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

j’attends - ol’ dirty digger, you can hear full version here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn4BF2TMawQ

Also for the future, you can use the [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/) app too.